# Migrating a stored procedure based solution to OOP?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, architecture, migration

At my company (which I joined recently), an ASP.net solution is used to provide a http based RESTful API for clients.

In facts, this "API layer" layer is very "thin" with a lot of methods that only contain 2 lines of code: converting parameters + calling a deeper layer.

So, the "API layer" passes the parameters it gets via http calls down to the next layer, which converts the properties to "business objects" which are mainly classes with properties only, nearly no logic. This "business layer" again passes the properties down to a "repository layer", which fills properties of another class (the "parameters class") which finally calls a stored procedure with these parameters.

Nearly all "business logic" is in "hidden" in stored procedures.

When they get called, they pass their out-parameters back to the C# repository layer class and converts it all back up to the "API Layer".

So in short: the C# classes to not really use any logic or OOP. In fact, they most likely could be created automatically from the stored procedure parameters because said simple: they collect API parameters, pass them down to the database (Oracle) to a stored procedure and pass the result of the stored procedure call back up to the API.

As you might expect from the described "architecture", no unit tests and integration tests exist at the moment.

The described architecture is rather old and I guess in the 80s it might have made some sense to create all BL in the database.

Since I am used to TDD, I started creating unit tests for the existing codebase, which was hard since it was not designed for testability in mind. Unfortunately, there also was not much to test beside from that the "correct" stored procedure is called with the "correct" parameters.

For the future, it is planned, that accessing the database via stored procedures should be the only allowed way, so moving to some kind of O/R mapper might be out of reach.

What do you think about this "architecture"?

It isn't similar to any (useful) code, I have seen in my career so far. (programming C# since version 1.0, C++ before)

I am used to TDD, writing business logic in C# classes, using OOP mechanism, SOLID code, patterns, ...

The database usually was the "persistence layer" only, which was accessed with an O/R mapper.

So I am not sure where to start. How would you start, converting this 80s "architecture" to a more OOP-style?

I would like to apply modern OOP programming style to create a maintainable, automatic testable and adaptive solution, not continue putting logic in store procedures and using C# just as a wrapper to call these procedures.

Maybe I could create a prototype that uses Entity Framework to do some basic CRUD and query operations by calling stored procedures?

Comment: The questions you're going to be asked will be along the lines of "What benefit does this rewrite provide to the business? Can you guarantee that there will be no need to rewrite other applications? How much time is this going to take?" And, management's favorite question: "How much is this going to cost?". I suggest it would be better to implement functionality needed by the business rather than embarking on a huge rewrite of a working code-base with no defined business benefit or goal.

Comment: The question might be a bit opinion-based, but here's a similar thread that covers the topic quite nicely: [How much business logic should the database implement?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194446/how-much-business-logic-should-the-database-implement)

Comment: Also, [this thread](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170808/do-stored-procedures-violate-three-tier-separation) (mentioned in the previous one) covers the same topic.

Comment: @BobJarvis and those are reasonable quesions indeed. Rewriting big old stable application just because you are used to OOP, SOLID and such stuff is usually not very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply!
I completely agree that there always has to be "business value" as a benefit, as soon as things require effort.

The problem with the "big old stable" application is that new features are required and also added constantly (in stored procuedures) but a lot of the code is already that old that no one known what it really does. Also no one knows, if adding new features might break the existing "stable application".

"Stability" is a must-have requirement, unfortunatelly in my opinion cannot be guranteed and when adding feature after feature without adding any tests -  thing will even further degrade.

At least thats my experience and I have been working in a project where exactly this happended to a codebase. Back these days we had no testing and didn't know  about good practicies. In fact after 3 years we had to throw away the whole codebase and start from scratch...and yes, this 2nd time we learned about good practices first and did it in a TDD way and the codebase is still adaptive enough to add new requirements, after 6 years.

So I already learned it "the hard way", why a testable and adaptive codebase is important and would prefer for me and my team not having to go this way again. :)